# how to apply csrf_token in django

Tags: javascript, django, django-forms, django-templates, dropzone.js

In Django Template Without using form i want to upload files to my web server. so for that i`m using javascript library called dropzonejs.

I exactly follow this tutorial [bootstrap dropzonejs](http://www.dropzonejs.com/bootstrap.html). I setup everything to run the demo.

You see i decided not to use `form` so obviously the problem `csrf_token` is missing when upload happens time.

**My doubt is how to include `csrf_token` in `javascript`.** ?

This is the information they added in their home page for how to add csrf token

> **sending** - Called just before each file is sent. Gets the xhr object and the formData objects as second and third parameters, so you can modify them (for example to add a CSRF token) or add additional data.

Are you understand my question ? give me some idea to do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could either have the view [CSRF exempt](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.csrf_exempt):

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

class YourView(models.View):

    @csrf_exempt
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(YourView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

The [JavaScript](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#ajax) config would probably look something similar to this:

```
(function($){
    $(function(){
      function getCookie(name) {
        var cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
            var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
                var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
                // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
                if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
                    cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return cookieValue;
    }
    var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

    function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
        return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
    }

    $.ajaxSetup({
        crossDomain: false,
        beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
            if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type)) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
            }
        }
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```